# Significance test for mean without assuming normality?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, nonparametric, matlab

I'm trying to do significance test with a set of data `X` and see if their distribution approximates the population mean `M`. It's easy to use t-test command `ttest(X, M)` in MATLAB but it assumes normality. I want a significance test that does pretty much the same thing but just does not assume normality. Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Here are a few thoughts:

- If you have sufficient data, you may not need your data to actually be normal, because the [Central Limit Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) will cover for you.  (What counts as "sufficient data" will depend on the manner in which your data are non-normal, though.)
- You can test for a difference in the medians (rather than means) using the [Mann-Whitney U-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U).  It's been a long time since I've used MATLAB, but I gather that's done with [mwwtest(X1,X2)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25830-mann-whitney-wilcoxon-test).
- You can always test for the difference in means by [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29).  You can search through some of CV's threads on bootstrapping by clicking here: [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap).  I found a MATLAB help page [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/bootstrp.html).

Comment: The Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test does not test medians but rather the Hodges-Lehman parameter related to pseudomedians.  The central limit theorem does not help in getting accurate confidence interval coverage except in the limit, unless you know $\sigma$ and don't have to estimate it.

Comment: @FrankHarrell +1 ... Though under a location-shift alternative WMW is also a test of means, medians and so on.

Comment: user28379 in addition to gung's suggestions, two more: (i) The traditional solution would be a permutation or randomization test; (ii) if you have some idea that the distribution might be some specific exponential family member, you could fit a GLM with a group indicator as the independent variable.